# ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(className) returning null when trying to load class file resource

Tags: java, class, resources, classloader

```
Class clazz = ...;
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

The input stream is returning null. I have used a simple java instrumentation agent to log classes as they are loaded and the class (clazz) is definitely being loaded by the ClassLoader. I've also tried

```
... Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...));
```

and it returns null as well. What would be some possible causes for the resource not being able to be found by the class loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Class has apparently been loaded by a different ClassLoader than the ones you're trying to find it with. Try this instead:

```
InputStream is = clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
    clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

Short of a flaw in the JVM, I don't think that can possibly return null.

Comment: I just attempted that and the class file still isn't able to be found. Could the problem be that the jar I added the class to is being used by a different jar (with the different jar containing the main class)?

Comment: No, jars are irrelevant to this unless they're OSGi bundles. What kind of environment are you running this in? Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: My apologies, what you suggested did end up fixing the problem where the class file could not be loaded as a resource. Now I'm getting a different problem where a NoClassDefFoundError is being thrown by a reflective call to ClassLoader.defineClass(...) because it isn't able to locate the same class that I was trying to load as a resource.

Comment: It seems obvious that you have at least two ClassLoaders that have different classes available to them, and it's messing with whatever you're doing. I'd suggest posting another question with a more complete explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe somebody can suggest an alternative that will work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()
Please make sure that the class file you tru to load in in classpath of your code.
Also couild you please share the value of clazz.getName() ?

EDIT:

Are you doing something like following ?

```
Class clazz = Dummy.class;
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

I mean to say that do you define clazz as *ClassName*.class ? If not then try doing this and then see.

Comment: I haven't tried that, I'll let you know the result. I assume that the class file is in the classpath because when I use a java agent to debug the loading of classes I see the name of the class that I'm trying to get as a resource output in my debug log. The value of clazz.getName() is "com.example.MyClass"

Comment: can you try prepending a back-slash(/) to clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class" and try

Comment: tried that to no avail. Could the problem be that the class is in a jar that is being used as a library for the main application? It's confusing because I'm able to reference the class in code, yet when I try to load the file as a resource it cannot be found.